# Disk Throughput Terminology

Tags: network-attached-storage, performance

Imagine running a test where you have a network-attached storage device, and there are two running processes (on different machines), reading and writing the same file on the NAS. Process 'W' does dedicated writes, and process 'R' does dedicated reads.

What is the correct terminology for the total time it takes a single byte written by 'W' to be made available for reading by 'R'? Is this throughput, latency or something else? This would factor in all protocol and network related latency.

*Edit: Actual problem is discussed below:*

We have a NAS device on our network, and a requirement that we read a growing file being written by one device (the 'W' process described above), on a second device (the 'R' process). We need to read very close to the tail of the file, and periodically we receive I/O errors ("Broken pipe"). We are trying to determine what is causing the broken pipe and tune the NAS accordingly.

Comment: What protocol do the computers use to access the NAS?

Comment: The writer process connects from Windows via CIFS, and the reader process connects on a Mac (Snow Leopard) via SMB (also CIFS, I suppose).

Comment: I will suggest that two programs that need to communicate in a tightly-coupled fashion should not do it via a file on remote storage.

Comment: @Dan: Does the reader hold file read locks when it reads/stats and the writer hold file write locks when it writes? How does the reader decide when to read/stat?

Comment: @mfinni I don't disagree, however, I have to work within our client's requirements.

Comment: @David As far as I know it's a standard read on the filesystem from a c++ program. On the NAS side, it's a black box to me. What should we look for when troubleshooting? Can we do it with wireshark?

Comment: @Dan If you're not using file locks, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @David CIFS locking is enabled, I know that. We tested with "oplocks" disabled, seemed not to have an effect

Comment: @Dan Right, but are the applications doing the reading and writing actually placing locks?

Comment: @Dan - but these programs don't have to work as your clients want them to, if they're trying to do something that the environment can't support.

Comment: @David on the read side the file is opened read only so probably not. On the write side, it's a windows process, so I believe windows will lock the file on a write. I will look into it however.

Comment: @Dan If Windows locked the file on a write and the program didn't close/reopen the file on every write, there either would have to be no write lock at all or a continuous write lock. With a continuous write lock, how could the reader ever get in? If you want to use a file this way, both ends have to be designed to use appropriate file locks at application level. Even then, it still might not work, but at least it has a chance.

Comment: Is there a way to query a file for its lock status?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where in the two-way chain of events you place this term, it could be "commit rate" or "commit time".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand the question, is this homework, if so please read our FAQ, we're not here for that kind of thing.

Anyway the answer is 'who knows' - because it depends on how long after the write it's committed on the filer and when the file is unlocked and its metadata is updated to reflect the change, only then will the reading app realise its cached copy has been updated so will read the updated data.

There's no set-time that's universal.

Comment: Homework ? on servefault ? oh noes!

Comment: This isn't homework, I am trying to troubleshoot what seems to be a disk performance problem but I don't know how to configure my test tools to get the correct metrics.

Comment: maybe discussing the actual problem with actual details might be more productive than a hypothetical

Comment: Ok, edited as requested.